Reason for discrepancy in calculated $\chi^2$ value in this right-side preference while kissing problem
In the article Adult persistence of head-turning asymmetry, the author observed $ 124 $ couples. $80 $ of them kiss by moving their head to the right. Remaining $44$ move their head to the left.
When I calculate the chi-square statistic using $50\%$ expected frequency $(62 + 62),$ I get $10.45$ as the chi-square statistic. But this paper reported $5.34$ as the chi-square statistic.
My calculation:




Right
Left




Observed
80
44


Expected
62
62



$\chi^2 = \frac{(80-62)^2}{62} + \frac{(44-62)^2}{62}$
$\chi^2 = 10.45 $
What am I doing wrong?

Nothing.
One way to tell is to apply a better test.  The null hypothesis is that each observation independently has a $1/2$ chance of being "right" and a $1/2$ chance of being "left."  The total of the "right" values among $124$ such observations therefore has a Binomial distribution with parameters $124$ and $1/2.$  The test relies on computing a p-value, defined as the chance of observing an $80-44$ split or one more extreme than that.  This chance is $0.0016.$  (I computed it in R with the expression
pbinom(44, 124, 1/2) + pbinom(80-1, 124, 1/2, lower.tail = FALSE)

formulated to display the underlying concepts.)
The chi-squared test is an approximation.  The p-values corresponding to the paper's chi-squared statistic of $5.34$ and to your value of $10.45$ (which I believe is correctly computed) are $0.021$ and $0.0012,$ respectively.  (These were computed in R as
pchisq(c(5.34, 10.45), 1, lower.tail = FALSE)

using one degree of freedom, as explicitly indicated in the paper.)
These values are $13$ times the correct one and $0.78$ times the correct one, respectively: neither is very good, but the one in the paper is an order of magnitude wrong.
Good ways to test hypotheses in this basic textbook situation are explained in the better elementary textbooks, such as the classic by Freedman, Pisani, and Purves.

whuber, I have added your post's link that extensively advocated for the book instead of the general thread (which in any case, OP can redirect to). However, it's implicit that you can revert back the edit if you feel so.
